# Get Channel Home Page URL from Json via PHP

Tags: php, json, video, youtube, gdata

I'm using JSON to get the video title, description, and author from the Youtube JSON API. How do I get the author's home page URL?

[Data](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/I6YeYnOTC-k?alt=json&prettyprint=true)

I'm trying to get [this](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZdr_9XUM9vrmkscUwnF42w).

I also noticed that sometimes, it's not `youtube.com/channel/xxxx`, but rather `youtube.com/user/xxxx` when I look at this:

hxxp://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/hha0NsYXS5c?alt=json&prettyprint=true
hxxps://www.youtube.com/user/TEDtalksDirector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example of

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/I6YeYnOTC-k?alt=json&prettyprint=true

1. Get the URI of the author, given by the API (in this case "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Zdr_9XUM9vrmkscUwnF42w")
2. Make a request to get JSON-Output of the user
3. Get the channel url under the link-href element(http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZdr_9XUM9vrmkscUwnF42w)

In the end you just grab the URI of the author, send a request to it and filter the JSON-Output.

Comment: Thanks!  That was it :) Here is the code in case anyone is interested:

    `$video_uri = $json['entry']['author'][0]['uri']['$t'];

    $video_uri = $video_uri. "?alt=json&v=2";

    $json_output = file_get_contents($video_uri);

    $json = json_decode($json_output, true);

    $channel_url=$json['entry']['link'][0]['href'];`

Comment: Can't figure out how to put code in properly, so here is another link: http://codepad.org/xEpiX470